# How do I stretch carpet during reinstallation after replacing padding?

Tags: flooring, carpet

I pulled up some carpet that is in front of a door way in order to replace the padding underneath, but when I laid it back down there was a slight gap and now if you step right on it you can feel the spike strip underneath (ouch!).

How can I get the fit snug so that I don't hit the spike strip anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Rent (or buy) a carpet stretcher.

Here is a [google search for carpet stretchers](https://www.google.com/search?q=carpet+stretcher).

Comment: That is the tool but not how a DIYer would do it.

Comment: depends on the design of the actual tool

Comment: How do I use a carpet stretcher?  Do I need a power stretcher, or can I use a knee kicker?

Comment: from the content of the OP, can you tell?

Comment: If the room is large and you only have a knee kicker, kick the room in parts and have someone use nails to hold the carpet place while you kick it the rest of the way.

Comment: I have laid 20' x 20' carpet successfully using only a knee kicker.  I tried using a power stretcher, but that was not as intuitive to get right without experience.  The knee kicker can only stretch a little bit at a time, especially with oneself kneeling on the carpet.  Patience is the key.  With the power stretcher, it is far to easy to do too much at once.

Answer (score 0):

Bend the offensive nails down, then caulk the gap.  Alternatively, fill the gap by caulking into place a strip of durable material.  Dry fit first to avoid making a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Screw down a strip of threshold to span across the gap.